# Sending Form Data in ASP.MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form like below. When I send the Form, the data (id,content,gdate) reaches the post ActionResult. However, a field (named "category") gets null in post side. What is the missing part?

BlogPost Model:

```
 public class BlogPost
{
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string content { get; set; }
    public virtual string gdate { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

}
```

Category Model:

```
public class Category
{
    public int ID{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
 public class CreateVM
{        
    public BlogPost BlogPost { get; 
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories;
}
```

Controller:

```
// GET: BlogPosts/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        CreateVM vm = new CreateVM();
        vm.Categories = new SelectList(db.Categories, "ID", "Name");
        return View(vm);
    }


        return View(vm);
    }

[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult Create(CreateVM vm)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.BlogPosts.Add(vm.BlogPost);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BlogPost.Category, Model.Categories);
```

Comment: `Category` is a complex object and you cannot bind a `<select>` (or any element) to a complex object. You should be using a view model with a property `int SelectCategory` (binding to `BlogPost.Category.ID` is not a good idea and if any properties of `Category` contained validation attributes, then `ModelState` would be invalid)

Answer (score 1):

Change your helper:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BlogPost.Category.ID, Model.Categories);
```

It will bind selected `Id` on post.

Then change your controller to get existent entity from db:

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult Create(CreateVM vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // this is the line where you should get your category entoty from DB. MAby you have different tables. it just example
        vm.BlogPost.Category = db.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == vm.BlogPost.Category.ID)
        db.BlogPosts.Add(vm.BlogPost);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: It works. The data comes to Action properly. For instance, category ID comes as '5'.  However, When I check the data table from SQL Explorer in the relevant row Category_ID seems as '8'. I do not know why?

Comment: @SuatAtan becouse EF think it's new entity. You should get existant from db in controller on post with FirstOrDefault() method

Comment: I could not do it. Could you elaborate it please?

Comment: @SuatAtan no problem, if it helps you - mark it as an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111242/discussion-between-suat-atan-and-teo-van-kot).

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your model and view inorder to make things work..

ViewModel:

```
public class CreateVM
{        
public BlogPost BlogPost { get; set;}
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories{ get; set;}
public int CategoryId{ get; set;}
}
```

View:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "ID", "Name"));
```

Note: Still the Category field will return null value only,but while posting the form you will see the selected Id value of the dropdown being filled with the respective one which will help in further processing the things..